# Difference between & and *

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the difference between these two operators?
My understanding is that they both point to the memory location of the variable they are used on.

Ex.

```
int p;
foo(*p,&p);
```

Comment: [Get a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282)

Comment: The expression `&p` returns the location (address) of the variable `p`.  The expression `*p` return the value that is at the location inside the `p` variable, often called *dereferencing*.  So if `p` contains the value `2020`, then `*p` will return the integer stored at location 2020 (if possible).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews In the code in the question, `*p` will not compile. The operand of unary `*` must be an expression of pointer type. A pointer cannot contain the value `2020` (which is of type `int`), though it might contain, for example, the value `(int*)2020`.

Comment: @KeithThompson "*The operand of unary `*` must be an expression of pointer type*" - or an instance of a class/struct type that implements a member `operator*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&p` gets the pointer to the integer `p` -> That is, the memory address in which `p` is stored.

`*p` "dereferences" the pointer, i.e. looks at the object at the memory address provided by `p` and returns that object.

Your code above is invalid C, as you cannot dereference an `int`:

`error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)`

Consider instead the following:

```
// Create an integer
int p = 1234;
printf("Integer: %d\n", p);

// Get the pointer to that integer, i.e. the memory address in which p is stored
int *pointer = &p;
printf("Pointer: %p\n", pointer);

// Dereference the pointer to get the value back
int q = *pointer;
printf("Dereferenced: %d\n", q);
```

Gives the following output:

```
Integer: 1234
Pointer: 0x7ffee53fd708
Dereferenced: 1234
```

*Also notice that to print out a pointer address, we have to use a special format specifier `%p` instead of the `%d` we'd use for an `int`.*

Comment: The code above has no behavior, nasty or otherwise. Given `int p;`, the expression `*p` will not compile.

Comment: Fair point :) I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
// declare an integer
int p = 42;

// declare a pointer type, and use it to store the address
// of the variable p. 
int* ptr = &p;

// use the * to dereference the pointer, and read the integer value
// at the address. 
int value = *ptr;
```